# unable to run PhantomJS under cygwin using absolute paths

Tags: cygwin, phantomjs

I am not able to run PhantomJS under cygwin using absolute paths for the argument .js file.  Here are the steps I took to setup PhantomJS:

1. Downloaded PhantomJS 1.9.7 for windows
2. Copied the PhantomJS executable to c:\cygwin64\bin\
3. Copied the file "hello.js" from the unzipped PhantomJS download file to my cygwin home directory
4. Started cygwin/xterm

If I run:

`which phantomjs`

in my cygwin xterm, it correctly responds with:

`/usr/bin/phantomjs`

If I run the following from my home directory:

```
phantomjs hello.js
```

PhantomJS correctly responds with:

```
Hello, world!
```

If I on the other hand run this:

```
phantomjs /home/user1/hello.js
```

PhantomJS replies:

```
Can't open '/home/user1/hello.js'
```

If I run this:

```
/usr/bin/phantomjs /home/user1/hello.js
```

PhantomJS still replies:

```
Can't open '/home/user1/hello.js'
```

It does this for every absolute path I try.  Why won't PhantomJS work with absolute file paths?  The path I showed in my example doesn't have any spaces, special characters, etc., so I'm not sure what the problem could be.

I also tried running the same test in a command prompt under windows and sometimes it would exhibit the same behavior, but not always.  I can't seem to reproduce this error under windows anymore so I'm not sure what else to say about that.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Have you tried `/cygdrive/c/home/user1/hello.js`?

Comment: I tried `/usr/bin/phantomjs /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/user1/hello.js` and it still says: `Can't open '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/user1/hello.js'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.  Running native windows programs through cygwin requires you to convert cygwin's POSIX paths to Windows-style paths.  In my example above, the following works:

```
phantomjs "`cygpath -w /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/user1/hello.js`"
```

returns:

```
Hello, world!
```

I am not yet sure what the backticks are for, but at least I found the solution.

Comment: You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/266187) your answer. Also, please look through your other questions. I think you find at least one answer that you can accept.